# Continuous transformation of a q-expansion into a Dirichlet series

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, dirichlet-series

I would like to know if series of the form  $ \sum_{n>0}a_{n}\dfrac{q^{tn}}{n^{z(1-t)}} $ where   $ t\in(0,1) $ , $ a_{n} $  is the  $ n $ -th Fourier coefficient of a cusp form of a given weight  $k $  and level  $ N $ and  $q=e^{2i\pi z} $ for  $ z $ in the upper half plane of complex numbers with positive imaginary part have been considered so far. If so, is the value of (the derivative of) such a series for  $ t=1/2 $ of interest ? Can an analogue of the Rankin-Selberg convolution be defined for such series ?

Comment: Why would these appear? In what context are you arriving at expressions of this form?

Comment: I just thought that instead of attaching an L-function to a modular form, which in some sense boils down to jumping discretely from the first to the second, it might be interesting to deform the first continuously into the second.

Comment: You need to study the basics of zeta functions, for example proofs of the functional equation. $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$, $f(q,z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n q^n n^{-z}$.  $\Gamma(s) F(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} f(e^{-x},0)dx$ and $$\Gamma(s) F(s+z) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} f(e^{-x},z)dx$$ 
With $q^{t n}$ it works the same after a change of variable $y = tx$. Rankin-Selberg convolution works well only for automorphic functions, otherwise it doesn't tell us anything. @mixedmath